# S3SinkConnector: Issue while consuming compressed data from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I have data in Kafka Topic which is Avro serialised and compressed using zstd codec. To transfer this data to S3 I have created a S3SinkConnector with below config -

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
    "s3.region": "ap-south-1",
    "topics.dir": "0/test_debezium_sept_12_mon_5/public/test_table",
    "flush.size": "10000",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "s3.part.size": "67108864",
    "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta",
    "rotate.interval.ms": "60000",
    "locale": "en_GB",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetFormat",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "s3.bucket.name": "zeta-aws-aps1-metis-0-s3-pvt",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "partition.duration.ms": "86400000",
    "schema.compatibility": "NONE",
    "topics": "cdc_test_debezium_sept_12_mon_5.public.test_table",
    "parquet.codec": "gzip",
    "connect.meta.data": "true",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": {{url}},
    "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
    "name": "cdc_test_debezium_sept_12_mon_5.public.test_table_cdc_zeta-aws-aps1-metis-0-s3-pvt_ap-south-1_sink",
    "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
    "path.format": "'date'=YYYY-MM-dd",
    "rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "180000",
    "timestamp.extractor": "RecordField",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "{{url}}",
    "timestamp.field": "cdc_source_ts_ms"
}
```

The above S3SinkConnector fails with following error

`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic cdc_test_debezium_sept_12_mon_5.public.test_table to Avro: \n\tat io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:118)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$0(WorkerSinkTask.java:492)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:146)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:180)\n\t... 13 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 1106\nCaused by: java.io.EOFException`

**NOTE: If I disable compression on producer/kafka side then S3 connector works fine. Issue is only while enabling compression on Kafka side.**

Comment: I don't think compression matters. Are you sure both the **key** and value in your topic are Avro? Avro keys are not common in Kafka topics, plus, you have not enabled the writing of the key to S3.

Comment: yes @OneCricketeer both key and value are Avro. The above config was working fine until I introduced compression on the source side.

Comment: Can you get id 1106 from the registry? Does that schema match the data produced?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I checked for the id 1106. It is giving me value of some other topic only. The topic in question is cdc_test_debezium_sept_12_mon_5.public.test_table whereas I am getting some other topic in response. Seems like a mismatch.

Comment: Can you also get each schema from subject `cdc_test_debezium_sept_12_mon_5.public.test_table-value/versions`? What ids do they have?

Comment: @OneCricketeer When I check the subjects in schema registry I can't find the one associated with above topic. Seems like the key and value of the compressed data are string and not Avro.

Comment: I changed the key and value converter to String in the S3 Sink Connector config but now it gives me Error Encoding Partition which is coming from here - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/blob/master/partitioner/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/partitioner/TimeBasedPartitioner.java#L326

Comment: ParquetFormat requires a Struct/map record type. If you want to use strings, you'll need to HoistField transform

Comment: I want to preserve the schema actually. 

Context: 
I want to store the data in Avro format in a compressed codec in Kafka and store this in the same compressed codec but in Parquet format in S3. 

Just the S3SinkConnector part is not working if my data is compressed in kafka. Before this my data in kafka was in Avro format but not compressed and the whole flow was working fine. 

What would you suggest @OneCricketeer

Comment: Yes, I understood the question. I'm not sure, really, because I've always used snappy compression with Avro data, and it worked fine (with AvroFormat, at least)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248334/discussion-between-antriksh-vijay-and-onecricketeer).